# Регулярные выражения C# числа

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Условие задачи почти полностью выполнено, застрял на моменте когда нужно вывесли кол-во нулей из всех вводимых чисел, не понимаю синтаксиса регулярного выражения https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level4/4_10.php как именно сделать чтобы считало число?
Сейчас программа выводит кол-во чисел в которых есть хотя бы один  0, нужно чтобы выводило именно кол-во 0-ей, как мне объяснили для этого используеются регулярные выражения, и я понимаю как парсить по символам, но мне нужно число

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter numbers – ");
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int x = 0;
        Regex regex = new Regex("0");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] splitLine = line.Split(' ');

        foreach (var sLine in splitLine)

        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(sLine))
            {
                x++;
            };
            int putnumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(sLine);
            if (putnumber > 0)
            {

                i++;

            }
            if (putnumber < 0)
            {
                j++;

            };



        };
        Console.WriteLine($"Positive numbers - {i}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Negative numbers - {j}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Zero's are - {x}");
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Regex.IsMatch` проверяет в целом строку на наличие шаблона. В случае если нужно получить все вхождения шаблона, то применяют функцию `Matches`. Вот пример для вашего случая.

```
x += regex.Matches(sLine).Count;
```

Если вам нужны только количество нулей в строке, то предлагаю другой вариант решения.

```
line.Count(c => c == '0');
```

Это функция посчитает за вас все символы в строке, которые эквивалентны нулю в строковом представлении.